# Tapping preview in context menu on iPad doesn't animate presentation of full screen view controller

Tags: ios, ipad, contextmenu

I have a context menu in my app that shows a photo preview above the actions, and tapping the preview presents that view controller full-screen. On iPhone, when you tap the preview there’s a lovely animation - it bounces into full screen. But on iPad, when you tap the preview the context menu dismisses and then the screen appears without any animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the (new*) default behavior on iPad. The idea being you can use your own presentation animation. To get the system "pop" style that's default on iPhone, set the `preferredCommitStyle` to `.pop` on the `UIContextMenuInteractionCommitAnimating` object.

*I think it changed in iOS 13.4. This change broke the Photos app as well.